# Finding odd number results using the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I am experiencing some problems with finding odd results w/ the user input. I am not sure how to code the for loop statement to get the odd results only. Current for loop statement is fixed to increment by two, but this will only work if the user enters odd numbers as well ex(0,5). Sorry i really dont have much experience with forloops, i tried nesting the for loops, but it only made it more confusing. This is my for-loop statement;

```
 for(counter = num1; counter <= num2; counter+=2){ //this is my for loop statement
       System.out.println(counter);//print out all of the odd values
     }
```

}

Comment: What are ``num1`` and ``num2``?

Comment: Provided `num1` is odd, then that will work (because you're jumping by two on each iteration). If `num1` is even, then that won't work (because you're jumping by two on each iteration).

Comment: `counter` is either always odd or never, since you're adding an even value

Comment: by _odd results_, do you mean every second result starting with 1st, 3rd,5th,6th, ...  \\   or if a result is odd e.g. the sequence 1,3,11,15,21 would all be odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to the accepted answer:

```
//if num1 is even, move it up to the next odd number
num1 |= 1;
```

It probably doesn't really matter, but I think it's neater that way.

Answer (score 2):

If a user enters an even number, just fix it before the loop:

```
//if num1 is even, move it up to the next odd number
if (num1 % 2 == 0) {
    num1++;
}

//print all of the odd values
for (int counter = num1; counter <= num2; counter+=2) {
    System.out.println(counter);
}
```

Comment: `num1 % 2 != 0` is only true when `num1` is already odd. I think you meant `==`

Comment: Yeah, I did. I was torn between using != 1 (for "not odd") and == 0 (for "even") and somehow had a brain fart and used the worst of both worlds. Fixed now.

Comment: why does it say i havent initialized counter when i already have.  ` int num1,num2,counter,i;`

Comment: @NotoriousBIG Because Sean uses `i` in his code and not `counter`. You need to fix that mistake.